# admob mediation with unity-ads or unity-ads mediation with admob. Which is better?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, unityads

If I apply admob sdk with unity ads on top using admob mediation for my android game made in unity or applying unity ads sdk with admob ads on top using unity mediation. which of them gives better output? if this is location dependent then please answer it for INDIA.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use AdMob mediation with Unity-Ads, for the following reasons:

1. AdMob is much get better revenue in India
2. AdMob has better tools for Ads than unity
3. Google is much better in Ads management than unity and have better support

Comment: But admob always limit the ads. It says  "ads are being limited". Admob has put ad limit on my account for almost a year now. What should i do?.

Comment: Ads limitation is due to violation of AdMob policy. This does not relate to the question.

Comment: No , what i mean is if i use admob on top of unity mediation then is there any chance that admob does not limit ad serving and my revenue is not affected.

Comment: I dont have any violation. Admob says "continue to develop your audience". What is the use of admob's better ecpm if it always put my account on limited ad serving.